# Swift 2.2 - Updating UILabel throws "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am new to iOS development so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. I have a view controller that contains a subview in which I've created a numpad, and for the time being I want to give the numpad view its own UIView subclass because I want to do a few different things with it. Right now the numpad is just creating a string from the keys that get pressed, and I've set up a delegate to pass that string anywhere else I want to use it (though I've also tried accessing the raw input directly in the view controller with let a = subview(); label.text = a.rawInput).

Whenever I try to set the text of the UILabel in the view controller to the subview's raw input, whether by delegation or directly, the UILabel is found to be nil and throws the error in the title.

Things I've tried:

- Setting the text inside a viewDidLoad override, and outside of it
- Setting a variable (testInput) inside the view controller to adopt the subview's raw input and setting the label text to that (I've confirmed that the variable inside the view controller gets properly set, so no delegation issues)
- Using didSet on the testInput variable both to set label text to testInput and to try calling viewDidLoad and set the label text in there (printing testInput inside this didSet does print the right string, FWIW)
- Deleting and relinking the IBOutlet for my label
- Strong and weak storage for the IBOutlet variable
- Trying to do the same thing in another subview within the view controller, in case for some reason it was the view controller's own fault
- Searching everywhere for a solution that works

I'm stumped. Here is my relevant numpad code:

```
import UIKit

protocol NumpadDelegate {
func updateInput(input: String)
}

class Numpad: UIView {

// MARK: UI outlets
@IBOutlet weak var decButton: UIButton!


// MARK: Properties
var rawInput: String = ""
var visibleInput: String = ""
var calcInput: String = ""
var operandReady = 1
var percentWatcher = 0

var delegate: NumpadDelegate? = BudgetViewController()



// MARK: Functions
func handleRawInput(str: String) {
    rawInput += str
    print("numpad input is \(rawInput)")

    delegate?.updateInput(rawInput)
}
```

And here is the view controller code:

```
import UIKit

class BudgetViewController: UIViewController, NumpadDelegate {

// MARK: Properties
//@IBOutlet weak var transactionValueField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var remainingCashForIntervalLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var intervalDenoterLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currencyDenoterLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainDisplayView: TransactionType!
@IBOutlet weak var inactiveInputView: InactiveInput!
@IBOutlet weak var numpadView: Numpad!
@IBOutlet weak var rawInputLabel: UILabel!


var remainingCashForInterval = 40

let display = TransactionType()
var testInput = "" {
    didSet {
        viewDidLoad()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//        let numpad = Numpad()
//        numpad.delegate = self
//        print("\(numpad.delegate)")
    self.rawInputLabel.text = testInput


}

func updateInput(input: String) {
    print("view controller now has \(input)")
    display.mainInput = input
    testInput = input
}
```

As a side note, in case you noticed that my protocol isn't a class type, for some reason adding : class to it and declaring my delegate as a weak variable prevents the delegation from working. Any suggestions there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned the delegate like so:

```
var delegate: NumpadDelegate? = BudgetViewController()
```

That doesn't reference the view controller whose scene was presented, but rather a new blank one. And that's why when you used `weak`, why it was deallocated (because that orphaned instance of the view controller has no strong references to it).

You should define the protocol to be a `class` protocol again, and define `delegate` to be:

```
weak var delegate: NumpadDelegate?
```

And then, in the view controller's `viewDidLoad`, uncomment the line that sets that delegate:

```
numpadView.delegate = self
```

But, do not uncomment the line that says `numpad = Numpad()`; that is incorrect as that creates yet another `Numpad` instance. But you do want to set the delegate of the existing `Numpad`, though.

---

Both of these issues (namely, getting a reference to the view controller that is to be the delegate of the `Numpad` view; and getting a reference to the `Numpad` view that the storyboard presented) suggest some misunderstanding about the the process of presenting a storyboard scene.

The process is basically as follows:

- the view controller is instantiated, using whatever class you specified as the base class for that scene;
- its root `view`, as well as all of the subviews on that scene will be instantiated for you;
- the storyboard will hook up the `IBOutlet` references in the scene's base class to the outlets you created; and
- the view controller's `viewDidLoad` is called.

That's an oversimplification, but that's the basic process.

But the key is that all of these view controllers and views that are referenced on the storyboard scene are created for you. You don't want to try to create any of these yourself (and the presence of the `()` at the end of `BudgetViewController()` or `Numpad()` says "create a new instance of *x*", which is not what we want to do here).

So, when we need to get a reference to the view controller so that we can programmatically specify the `delegate` for one of the views, you can do this in `viewDidLoad`, at which point `self` references the view controller that the storyboard instantiated for us. We don't want to instantiate a new one. Likewise, when you want to reference the `Numpad` that the storyboard instantiated for us (in order to hook up its `delegate`), you use the `IBOutlet` you hooked up in Interface Builder, rather than programmatically instantiate a new `Numpad` with `Numpad()`.

Comment: typo on `weak var delegate; NumpadDelegate?`. `:` instead of `;`

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I uncomment that line but not the numpad = Numpad() one, numpad is an unresolved identifier. If I change it to Numpad.delegate = self, it says "instance member 'delegate' cannot be used on type 'Numpad'." If I change it to Numpad().delegate = self, there is no error, but the delegation stops working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, you called it `numpadView`. (Sorry, I just saw the commented code and assumed that was the property name, but didn't look back at the name you used when you defined the property.)

Comment: No I didn't, unless I'm completely missing something I mistyped

Comment: In the code in your question, you have a line that says `@IBOutlet weak var numpadView: Numpad!`.

Comment: oh, thank you, it works now! I thought you meant the class itself. Would there be no way to do this if I had not created the IBOutlet for the numpad's view?

Comment: If you have no outlet to the `Numpad` instance in your storyboard, then you don't have any convenient way to reference the `Numpad` that was created by the storyboard when the scene was instantiated. And thus setting its  `delegate` would be difficult. The outlet provides a very simple way to reference something on the storyboard.